# Finding the indices of all edges within k steps from a chosen line in an adjacency matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph-theory, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

I have a function where I can find all nodes k number of steps from any initial set of nodes in a sparse adjacency matrix. Normally this initial set is the to-from node for a single branch. I want a list of the branches "used" to reach these nodes.

The function I use to find the connected nodes is as follows:

```
% nb = number of buses in the system
% branch_list = [from to] = the from/to nodes of each branch
adj_mat = sparse(from,to,1,nb,nb);
node_vec0 = sparse([from to],1,1,nb,1);
A = adj_mat + speye(nb);  % Add 1's on the diagonal of the adjacency matrix
node_vec = A * node_vec0; % Vector containing all nodes connected to node_vec0
```

I can repeat the last line k times, and find all nodes k steps from the inital nodes.

What I want to do, is to find the row (in the branch list) of each branch used to reach these nodes.

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use k-shortest path algorithm to achieve what you want. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing)

Comment: The algorithm seems a bit too complicated for what I'm trying to achieve. Do you have an idea if breadth-first search alone will be faster than using the method above to determine all nodes closer than k-steps away, followed by the k-shortest path algorithm, with these nodes as destination nodes, to find the branches?

Comment: You may be able to use depth-first-search, where depth can be interpreted as the distance between the nodes.